# JavaScript code syntax for bool value assignment to html object

Tags: javascript, html

below is code , both code works but i am trying to findout which is more perfect for browsers

Which code is right?

```
   <script>

document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=true;

</script>
```

or

```
<script>

document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled='true';

</script>
```

also when we compare in

```
if(document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled ==true)
```

or

```
if(document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled =='true')
```

Comment: A related subject (but actually a different issue) is the difference between the `disabled` attribute in the HTML tag and the `disabled` property of the DOM object, which is another great source of confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boolean. The string only works because when it is cast to a boolean it is evaluated as `true`. If you were to assign `"false"` then that string would also be evaluated as `true`.

Comment: Thumb rule: strings with values like `'true'`, `'YES'`, `'Y'`... are normally meaningless in languages with actual data types.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand which values evaluate to `false` in JavaScript. Falsy values are: `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0` `-0`, `""`, and `false`. This means that **everything** else evaluates to `true`:

```
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=true /* True */
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled="true" /* True */
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled="false" /* True */
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled="banana" /* True */
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=1 /* True */
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=4723598495 /* True */
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=false /* False */
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled="" /* False */
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=0 /* False */
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=NaN /* False */
```

Because of this and as you can see above, "false" is evaluated to `true` as it is a string with length greater than 0.

On the subject of which is *right*, the answer would be that both are. Both get the job done. You may as well just use `disabled=true`, however, to avoid potential confusion at a later date.